# SQL: please improve my select-where-subquery-returns-one query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql5

I already have a working solution to the following problem, but I worry that it is silly or inefficient.

There is a `Thing` table with columns `(id, attributes...)` and also a `ThingVersion` table with columns `(id, thing_id, version_attributes...)` The problem is to select from `Thing` where exactly one corresponding `ThingVersion` row exists.

At the moment I have something like

```
SELECT Thing.id AS id, Foo.whatever
FROM Thing JOIN Foo ON Thing.id=Foo.thing_id
WHERE Thing.id IN (
    SELECT thing_id FROM ThingVersion TV
    WHERE 1 = (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM ThingVersion TV2
        WHERE TV2.thing_id = TV.thing_id)
    )
ORDER BY Foo.whatever
```

It seems to give the correct results, and as an emphatic non-guru it seems self-explanatory, but -- *three* selects?!?! -- I can't help but feel there must be a better way.

Is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `HAVING` clause in your subquery:

```
SELECT Thing.id AS id, Foo.whatever
  FROM Thing JOIN Foo ON Thing.id=Foo.thing_id
 WHERE Thing.id IN
        ( SELECT thing_id
            FROM ThingVersion TV
           GROUP BY thing_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
 ORDER BY Foo.whatever
;
```

You can also eliminate the `JOIN` in the main query:

```
SELECT thing_id AS id, whatever
  FROM Foo
 WHERE thing_id IN
        ( SELECT thing_id
            FROM ThingVersion TV
           GROUP BY thing_id
          HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
        )
 ORDER BY whatever
;
```

(I'm assuming that every value that appears in both `Foo.thing_id` and `ThingVersion.thing_id` must certainly appear `Thing.id`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Thing.id AS id, Foo.whatever
FROM Thing JOIN Foo ON Thing.id=Foo.thing_id
where Thing.idin (select thing_id from ThingVersion group by thing_id having COUNT(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using strictly JOINs:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM Thing t
JOIN ThingVersion tv1
  ON tv1.thing_id = t.id
LEFT JOIN ThingVersion tv2
  ON tv2.thing_id = t.id
  AND tv2.id <> tv1.id
WHERE tv2.id IS NULL
```

Solution using GROUP BY and COUNT:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM Thing t
JOIN ThingVersion tv
  ON tv.thing_id = t.id
GROUP BY t.id
HAVING COUNT(t.id) = 1;
```

Try them both out for performance.

Comment: +1 Joins will almost definitely out perform the `GROUP BY ... HAVING` Solutions.